# How to setup Handsontable Pro with Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable

I have an Angular 5 app using `"angular-handsontable": "~1.0.0-beta3"`. The project seems to work fine with Handsontable Community Edition. But I can't get it to work with Handsontable Pro version 1.15.1.

Here's the setup structure, I am using now:

In `polyfills.ts` file:

```
import 'handsontable';
```

In tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
         "handsontable": [
            "node_modules/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.js"
          ]
       },
       ***FEW MORE LINES***
  }
}
```

In `app.module.ts` file:

```
import {HotTableModule} from 'angular-handsontable';
```

and in the `app.component.ts` file:

I tried passing the **PRO** feature `hiddenRows`, which didn't work. I didn't even get the message

> "Evaluation version of Handsontable Pro. Not licensed for use in a
>   production environment"

which I am supposed to get when using Handsontable Pro version without the license key. So it seems like my setup isn't configured properly.

Please help me solve this issue.